# mpirun for python script is not running as expected

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

To start off, I am very new to mpi, so I do deeply apologize for what could be an extremely trivial issue.

I am trying to run a python program in parallel on my laptop before I go ahead and run it on my university's local cluster. I've had success using Pool from multiprocessing; however, I now need to create a pool using MPIPool from schwimmbad.

The main component of the code that parallelizes things is as follows.

```
from schwimmbad import MPIPool

"""
Various other components of the code...
"""

with MPIPool() as pool:


    if not pool.is_master():
        pool.wait()
        sys.exit(0)

"""
The code continues....
"""
```

"pool" is then fed into an object from a different library that does its own thing. This is the same code as what is used for multiprocessing with the replacement of MPIPool from schwimmbad with Pool from multiprocessing and the deletion of the "if not pool.is_master()..." block of code. I have two cores on my laptop, so to execute this program, I enter the following into a terminal.

```
mpirun -n 2 python3 script.py
```

I expected this command to run a single program and for pool to distribute the processes over those two cores. What it seems like actually occurs is two copies script.py are run on each core separately. This is confirmed by the fact that everything I tell the program to print out before the main part of the code is executed prints twice and the program runs considerably slow compared to how it runs using the multiprocessing module.

I also tried to run someone else's code that also uses MPIPool with the same command and the same thing occurs - their program runs twice.

How can I get mpirun to just run a single program with its processes distributed over the two cores on my machine, like it would if I had just used the multiprocessing module?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I've clarified the question at the very end, my apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MPI and Python's multiprocessing are actually two quite different systems for running distributed processes.

- *Multiprocessing* is based on the principle that your main program starts new processes when needed.  To reduce the overhead of starting a new process, you can create a pool of other processes at the very beginning and then use that pool.  But even then, it is still your main program that spawns off all those other processes.
- *MPI*, on the other hand, is based on the idea that you run the same script in different processes and make these different copies talk to each other (MPI is a messaging interface).  The different processes are neither started by, nor under direct control of any individual copy of your program.  Rather, you have an external manager `mpirun` for that.

The graphic below shows the difference: MPI on the left has a manager that starts four equivalent copies of the same script—each with a different *rank* to distinguish them by.  Multiprocessing on the right has a main program that then spawns off other instances.  Accordingly, multiprocessing can be run just like a normal Python script and does not require something like `mpirun`.

[image]

To come back to your question: when using multiprocessing, the main script can send off tasks to other processes.  Even in the case of a pool: unless one of those secondary processes receives something to do, they usually just wait.  With MPI, each process just works through the same program in parallel and each process acts as if it is the only process running the script.  Here, you use the process's rank to distinguish what they are doing, and you use communication to synchronise their action and processing.